# Is it possible assign static IP addresses to HTTP API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

We need to provide static IPs to our API GW **using HTTP API GW** *- and not REST API GW*.

It's a tricky process, but here is a good resource about it from [AWS official docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/accessing-an-aws-api-gateway-via-static-ip-addresses-provided-by-aws-global-accelerator/).

The problem is there are only a few articles about it, and [it seems that is not possible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html) by using `HTTP` API GW, and only by using `REST` API GW.

Suggestions?

Comment: Probably you have to setup a reverse proxy for that on ec2 instance(s), if you don't want to use rest api.

Answer (score 0):

From the AWS Support team reply:

As you have correctly indicated, this can be configured for an API Gateway REST API by making use of AWS Global Accelerator [1]. However, this would unfortunately not be possible for an API Gateway HTTP API. The closest recommendation that I can make to achieve your use-case would be to possibly use an EC2 instance or a proxy service where you can configure a static IP and then forward the requests to your HTTP API.

> As @Marcin has commented.